# Polynomials of degree $n$ with $\Bbb{F}_p$ are always reducible in $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}$

Tags: polynomials, field-theory, finite-fields

This is a rather basic question, but I can't seem to find any reference here on StackExchange. Is it true that, given a polynomial $p(x) \in \Bbb{F}_p[x]$ of degree $n$, we have that $p(x)$ is always reducible in $\Bbb{F}_{p^n}[x]$?

If it is not true, then I'm in particular more interested in the case where $n = 2$.

Comment: If $f\in F_p[x]$ is irreducible then $F_p[x]/(f)$ is a field with $p^n$ elements. This implies that it is the splitting field of $x^{p^n}-x\in F_p[x]$, there is only one (up to isomorphism), called $F_{p^n}$, where $f$ is reducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true. If $P(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb F_{p^n}$ then it is certainly irreducible over $\mathbb F_{p}$. But that means that $\mathbb F_p(\alpha)$ for some root $\alpha$ of $P$ is a degree $n$ extension of $\mathbb F_p$, and hence equal to $\mathbb F_{p^n}$, and so $P(x)$ would have a root in $\mathbb F_{p^n}$, contradicting the initial assumption that it was irreducible.

Comment: Please change $p$ to $P$ to denote the polynomial. Otherwise it may cause confusion.

Comment: Good point! Thanks.